# Multiple relatedByAttributes in CoreData/MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Is it possible to set several `relatedByAttribute` keys for the entity attribute? If all of these primary keys are unique then the entity itself will be unique.

UPD: Yes, I've missed that. The `relatedByAttribute` is for Magical Record framework.

Comment: Is your question about MagicalRecord's "relatedByAttribute" feature? Then you should add that information to your question, and perhaps an example what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what you mean by "relatedByAttribute", when typed like that.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't currently supported by MagicalImporting. My suggestion is to first, create a github issue so we know you want it. Then, if we're not fast enough to implement it (which is **HIGHLY** likely) is suggest digging into the source a little and adding this support and submitting a pull request.